# Limit max number of simulataneous connections from NLB to a specific instance

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I am trying to restrict maximal number of TCP connections from amazon NLB to a target group.
Example of a desired scenario:

We have 2 instances and NLB. The first 100 users with 100 TCP connections are directed to the first instance and are connected for 1 hour. During this hour another 100 users connect to NLB and are directed to the second instance. The user number 201 is not allowed to connect.

I have not found any metric on NLB or autoscaling group which can allow restriction by conenction number. Is it possible with NLB?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that's not possible.  You could try and trigger AutoScaling, but its not going to be instant.  If you need that kind of custom logic you'd need to use a 3rd party solution to act as a load balancer, like HAProxy or NGINX